# CPU and HDDs temperature in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: hardware, cpu, disk, temperature, conky

I have a `conky` config using `hhdtemp` and `hwmon` to retrieve CPU and HDDs temperature.
Now in Ubuntu 22.04 those packages are not available anymore, what alternative do I have?

I need something from CLI, to use it in my `conky` config, that just prints the CPU and HDDs temperature in celsius.

Thanks

Comment: I have never used `hddtemp` but I am still using `hwmon` in Conky config on 22.04 LTS without any issues. How are you trying to use it, what is your config? I use like this: `${hwmon coretemp temp 2}` or `${hwmon acpitz temp 1}` etc. `hwmon` is a Conky object not a CLI command.

Comment: I don't why but that `hwmon` command does not work for me. I tried to run `for m in /sys/class/hwmon/* ; do echo -n “$m = ” ; cat $m/name ; done` and I can see only:
`“/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0 = ”k10temp
“/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon1 = ”hid_f4:73:35:63:56:22_battery`

Answer (score 10):

To read CPU and HDD temperatures in Ubuntu 22.04 you need to use `hwmon`, which can be accessed using `sensors`. HDD temperatures are included in the output when the `drivetemp` module is loaded.

```
sudo apt install lm-sensors
sudo modprobe drivetemp
sensors
```

To make `drivetemp` load automatically every boot, add it to /etc/modules as follows:

```
echo drivetemp | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

Answer (score 10):

I'm using everyday the application that display the temperature of CPU, HDD and also Graphic card in the top bar of the screen.

It's called `Psensor`. It's available in **Ubuntu Software**.

Comment: `psensor` isn't available from the CLI though